# US visa for a remote employee

Tags: visas, usa

My US employer wants to fly me in for the end of the year party with coworkers. They hired me as an independent contractor years ago and this job is my main source of income.

I don't live in US nor I have ever been there. The idea is to come there for a party and stay 2-3 days and flight right back to a country when I live. What would be the most appropriate visa to apply to minimize the chance of rejection? I am from Europe, but currently living in Asia.

Comment: Are you a citizen of a visa waiver program country?

Comment: Unfortunately, my country is not the one included in the visa waiver program. We're also still in a process of becoming a member of European Union.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not VWP eligible, have you looked at the B visa for visitors? Some helpful info here on B visas including the combined [B-1/B-2](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-visitors-business/b-1-temporary-business-visitor) for business and leisure related activity.

Comment: Hi there, for this to be potentially a good answer, can you please put in a US Government link to B1/B2 visa, instead of one from a private visa service?

Comment: My edit was to replace the link with the official US site (and as it read, it might have been viewed as spam, which Travel Stack Exchange does now allow).